# WCF config file 413-request-entity-too-large

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i have read multiple similar threads but still don't know what to do.
I've created simple WCF service which is getting some xml data (in strings)
Everything was working fine until project was running on windows 7.
Now, when i try to send data from client to WCF service i get exception

> 413-request-entity-too-large

i've tried to add these two parameters to my web.config on WCF service

```
  maxBufferSize="2147483647"    
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
```

Can someone please look at my config and try to help me ?

WCF service code:

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public static Konfiguracja config;
        public static DBqueries queries;
        public void WczytajKonfiguracje()
        {
            config = new Konfiguracja();
            queries = new DBqueries();
        }
        public bool? DodajInfoSprzet(int idKlienta, string haslo, int id_zgloszenia, string HardwareInfoXML, string SoftInfoXML)
        {
         ...and some code
        }
}
```

and here is my wcf web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjektSerwisConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sql12;Initial Catalog=ProjektSerwis;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

(i've edited it by visual studio context menu on file web.config)

WCF service has been running by

```
namespace SelfService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55555/WcfStart/");
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);

            try { 
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "WmiService");
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            selfHost.Open();
            while(true)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Usługa działa");
                Console.WriteLine("Wpisz quit aby zakończyć działanie");
                string command = string.Empty;
                command=Console.ReadLine();
                if (String.Equals(command.ToLower(), "quit".ToLower()))
                        break;
            }
                // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.  
                selfHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);  
                selfHost.Abort();  
            }
}
    }
}
```

and client has just references to web service and connect it by :

```
  Service1Client scl = new Service1Client();
            bool? ok = false;
            try
            {
                ok = scl.DodajInfoSprzet(IdKlienta, haslo, IdZgloszenia, HardwareInfoXML, SoftInfoXml);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```

i konw that i have pasted a lot of code, but i have no idea what to do with my web.config file

the data which is being sending is not big, it is less than 1 MB

Answer (score 0):

Did you just put this configuration in the web.config?

Since you're hosting your WCF as a console application you have to make the configuration in the App.config of the hosting application.